# If a noun clause acts as the subject of a sentence, is it no longer a dependent clause?

Tags: clauses

If a noun clause acts as the subject of a sentence, is it no longer a dependent clause?

For example:

- "What he did was outrageous."

I just saw this on a site so I wanted to see if it's true or not.

Comment: Consider [this example](https://www.lexico.com/grammar/clauses): *After we had had lunch [subordinate clause], we went back to work [main clause].* That would still be the same if we change ***After*** to ***When***, and I can't see the basic syntactic categories changing if we shift to ***When we finished lunch** [it was starting to get late].* In short, I can't see a big difference between ***When he did [it]*** (which seems unquestionably to be a dependent clause) and ***What he did***. But whether that's a ***useful*** categorisation is another question entirely.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was taken aback because up until recently, none of the sites I used mentioned that particular condition. It actually made sense too.

Comment: Well, if the categorisation *matters* to you (because you've got to know it to pass an exam, perhaps) then don't rely on anything I said. I don't really know or care what teachers of grammatical terminology would say about it (almost all of what I *really* think is contained in the final sentence above! :)

Comment: So far, I haven't seen other sites mention it so I might ignore it. My English teachers never mentioned it, so it might be like how some teachers subscribe to the alleged "don't end a sentence with a preposition" rule.

Comment: "What he did" is not a clause but a **noun phrase** in a fused relative construction. It means "that which he did" (or "the thing that he did")

Answer (score 1):

> [*What he did*] *was outrageous*.

"What he did" is not a noun clause (even if there were such a thing, which there isn't), but a noun phrase in a fused relative construction.

The pronoun "what" is simultaneously head of the whole noun phrase and object (in prenuclear position) in the relative clause.

It means "That which he did* (or the thing that he did") was outrageous".

EDIT: Below is a tree diagram of a similar example showing the structure of a fused relative construction with "what" in prenuclear position. As the diagram shows, "what" is co-referenced by the *i* subscript to the direct object in the nucleus clause.

[image]

Comment: I am not quite clear on "in prenuclear position". Can you talk a little more on that?

Comment: @EddieKal I've edited my answer by adding a diagram of a similar example. Hopefully, this will make things clearer.

Comment: This is great. Every point is explained.